# Custom MySQL bigint(11) comparisons are failing

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

there seems to be a bug in my program and it's quite weird. To test I was running some very simple commands on the manage.py shell.

```
models = Model.objects.all()

for model in models :
   print model.field

output: 
0
0
0
0
100004398604871
576962717
576962717
576962717
```

Now for the weird part:

```
Model.objects.extra(where = ["field= 576962717"])
output:
[]

Model.objects.extra(where = ["field= 100004398604871"])
output:
[]

# But!!

Model.objects.extra(where = ["field= 0"])
output:
[a bunch of models, aka this one worked]
```

So obviously something is wrong with the big int comparisons. I checked my mysql database structure and my models to make sure they aligned, and they did:

My mysql cols were labeled as bigint(11)

and my django models were BigIntegerField(editable=False)

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Seeing you fixed the error yourself, you might stop adding the display length to the integer columns because they do more harm than good obviously :)

Comment: It is said that using 11 or 20 with integer definitions is irrelevant. Did changing 11 to 20 resolve your case ? Also, is there something special in not writing "normal" Django like models.filter(field=576962717) ?

Comment: You are right, the problem ended up being fixed but it was for a different reason, not any better though. Forgot to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Oh god im slow, I forgot it was supposed to be bigint(20) not 11, sorry!